# PostgreSQL VACUUM ANALYZE does not resolve bloated index leading to poor query performance

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-administration

*Edit: I've heavily edited this question from it's original form because I made some incorrect assumptions which made the question nonsensical.*

My database version is `PostgreSQL 11.15`

I have a table (`transaction`):

```
Table "public.transaction"
      Column       |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                       Default
-------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------
 transaction_id    | bigint                   |           | not null | nextval('transaction_transaction_id_seq'::regclass)
 created_at        | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
 source_type       | character varying        |           | not null |
 source_id         | character varying        |           | not null |
 source_event_type | character varying        |           | not null |
 source_event_id   | character varying        |           |          |
 ingested_at       | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | now()
 member_account_id | character varying        |           |          |
 reason            | character varying        |           |          |
 reversed_at       | timestamp with time zone |           |          |
 reverses          | bigint                   |           |          |
Indexes:
    "pk_transaction" PRIMARY KEY, btree (transaction_id)
    "ix_transaction_created_at" btree (created_at)
    "ix_transaction_ingested_at" btree (ingested_at)
    "ix_transaction_member_account_id" btree (member_account_id)
    "ix_transaction_reverses" btree (reverses) INVALID
    "ix_transaction_source_event_id" btree (source_event_id)
    "ix_transaction_source_event_type" btree (source_event_type)
    "ix_transaction_source_id" btree (source_id)
    "ix_transaction_source_type" btree (source_type)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_transaction_reverses_transaction" FOREIGN KEY (reverses) REFERENCES transaction(transaction_id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "transaction" CONSTRAINT "fk_transaction_reverses_transaction" FOREIGN KEY (reverses) REFERENCES transaction(transaction_id)
```

The query planner isn't using the index on `reverses`.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE reverses = 1
>
Gather  (cost=1000.00..593734.62 rows=1 width=134)
  Workers Planned: 2
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on transaction  (cost=0.00..592734.52 rows=1 width=134)
        Filter: (reverses = 1)
```

Setting `enable_seqscan` to `off` gives the same query plan:

```
SET enable_seqscan = ON;
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE reverses = 1;
>
Gather  (cost=1000.00..593734.62 rows=1 width=134)
  Workers Planned: 2
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on transaction  (cost=0.00..592734.52 rows=1 width=134)
        Filter: (reverses = 1)
```

How do I find out why the query planner isn't using this index?

Comment: It says wastedibytes_pretty=0 for that index, so it doesn't seem like the index is bloated.  I doubt bloat would cause this, anyway. What if you query with enable_seqscan=off?

Comment: `cloudsql.max_free_memory` `google_insights.allocate_memory`  This does not look like the community version of PostgreSQL.

Comment: It's not it's a cloudsql instance. sorry I should have mentioned that.

Comment: after running `pg_repack` I received this error:
`WARNING: skipping invalid index: CREATE INDEX ix_transaction_reverses ON public.transaction USING btree (reverses)`

Which points me towards the real problem - that the index is invalid, nothing to do with the table bloat. This is verified with:

```SELECT relname, indisvalid FROM pg_class, pg_index WHERE pg_index.indisvalid = false AND pg_index.indexrelid = pg_class.oid;```

Comment: Something weird is going, but I don't think it is autovac related.  Check indisvalid, 
indcheckxmin, and indisready of pg_index

Comment: Oh, so you already did.  Then you can just reindex the index, or drop it and create it again (with CONCURRENTLY if you want).  I don't know how it got into that state, from my knowledge it is always either due to a crash during CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY, or due to unique key violations during CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY.  But maybe pg_repack can cause this state too.

Comment: Question 1 and 3 are answered, and we don't have enough data to answer 2: to me it looks like more than 1% is dead. @jjanes If you cancel a `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY`, you end up with an invalid index.

Comment: Yes. Thanks, this question as I original wrote it doesn't really make sense as I was blaming bloat for the problems rather than the invalid index.  I'm going to rewrite the question but split the parts about the invalid index and bloat into separate questions incase it's helpful for others.

Answer (score 2):

The index was not valid which is clear from the output of `\d transaction`:

> `"ix_transaction_reverses" btree (reverses) INVALID`

You can check for other invalid indexes using this query:

```
SELECT 
    relname, indisvalid 
FROM 
    pg_class, pg_index 
WHERE 
    pg_index.indisvalid = false AND 
    pg_index.indexrelid = pg_class.oid;
    enter code here
```

Which in this case returns

```
relname                |indisvalid|
-----------------------+----------+
ix_transaction_reverses|false     |
```

[The docs say:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html)

> If a problem arises while scanning the table, such as a deadlock or a uniqueness violation in a unique index, the CREATE INDEX command will fail but leave behind an “invalid” index. This index will be ignored for querying purposes because it might be incomplete; however it will still consume update overhead.

> The psql \d command will report such an index as INVALID

> The recommended recovery method in such cases is to drop the index and try again to perform CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY. (Another possibility is to rebuild the index with REINDEX INDEX CONCURRENTLY).

Comment: But note that REINDEX INDEX CONCURRENTLY does not exist until v12.